# "Delete DE" SSJS script is not working within my automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have an automation that fires an SSJS scripts at the end of it which is supposed to delete the contacts in the target DE (yes, the target DE is Sendable). When I test the following script in a cloudpage, it works, but when it's fired as part of an automation, it does nothing...Can someone take a look at the code below and tell me if I'm missing something? FYI - urls/keys modified.

```
Platform.Load( "Core", "1" );

var url                 = "https://mcwrpx6qhhjx04wnb-fdsad1g81.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
var contentType         = "application/json";
var payload             =   {grant_type  : "client_credentials"
                            , client_id  : "myClientID"
                            , client_secret : "myClientSecret"
                            };
var accessTokenResult   = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
var tokenObj            = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult.Response[0]);
var accessToken         = tokenObj.access_token;

if(accessToken != '')
{
    var endpoint        = "https://mcwrpx6qhhjx04wnb-0nr7gda68.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/";
    var apiEndpoint     = "contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference";
    var url1            = endpoint+apiEndpoint;
    var contentType1    = "application/json";

    var payload1        =   {
                                deleteOperationType: "ContactAndAttributes"
                                , targetList:   {
                                                    listType:{listTypeID:3},
                                                    listKey: "my-DE-External-key"
                                                }
                                , deleteListWhenCompleted: false
                                , deleteListContentsWhenCompleted: true
                            };
    var headerNames     = ["Authorization"];
    var s1              = "Bearer ";
    var headerValues    = s1.concat(accessToken);
    var result          = HTTP.Post(url1, contentType1, Stringify(payload1), headerNames, [headerValues]);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the automation in root Business Unit? When you say, that it doesn't work in an automation. What does it mean? Does it throw an error? Are the contacts not deleted? Mind you, the deletion happens asynchronously, and you can monitor the status under Contact Builder > Contacts Analytics, where all the contact deletion requests are shown. Once you can see a request is processed successfully, your record should be gone. They will not be deleted immediately after script execution. Depending on the number, it can take several days.

Comment: 1. Yes the automation is in root BU
2. It doesn't throw an error, but the contacts should delete (i.e. in var payload1, deleteListContactsWhenCompleted: true, this deletes the records in the DE when tested via a Cloudpage) I checked in Contact Builder and the deletes are not processing